# Drupal Field collection & Service module

Tags: xml, api, drupal, service

Has anyone tried to build a drupal7 service view that has a field collection, I tried this patch https://drupal.org/files/1180574-integration-with-services-11.patch but it didn't work, the second parameter is an empty array.

Regards,

Comment: Any luck with it? I am stuck at the same point